# OnEntryAdded doesn't fire in RadDropDownTree When I Change the Value of the DropDownTree

Tags: asp.net, telerik, dotnetnuke

I Have This in the ascx

```
<div >
<telerik:RadDropDownTree ID="RadDropDownTree1" runat="server" Width="250px" EnableFiltering="True"
    Skin="Metro" DataFieldID="ID" DataFieldParentID="Parent" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Code" 
    OnEntryAdded="RadDropDownTree1_EntryAdded1" OnEntryRemoved="RadDropDownTree1_EntryRemoved1">
    <dropdownsettings height="200" AutoWidth="Enabled" />
    <buttonsettings showclear="false" />
    <filtersettings highlight="Matches" emptymessage="Type here to find a Department" />
</telerik:RadDropDownTree>
</div>
```

and in the server side

```
protected void RadDropDownTree1_EntryAdded1(object sender, DropDownTreeEntryEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

protected void RadDropDownTree1_EntryRemoved1(object sender, DropDownTreeEntryEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

But No Exception thown with the changing of the DropDownTree

Answer (score 0):

1. Try setting `AutoPostBack` to `true`.
2. Make sure `AutoEventWireUp` in your Page Directive is set to `true`

Comment: You can then mark the answer as an answer for anyone having the same issue in the future.